# React Native change two parents state in a single function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to change two states in the parent component of my `loginForm` with in one EventListner (if this is the right term for the function).

Currently I'm only able to pass the value of one event trough to the parent, but I want to do both (for efficient coding)

The only solution I've found so far is to create two functions, which do essentially the same. (change a state) So far I've been told it's bad ethics to create the same function twice

Parent Component

```
changeStateValue = setEmail  => {
      this.setState({
        email:setEmail,
        password: setPassword,
        email_valid: this.validateEmail(setEmail),
      })
    }
    render() {
      const { email, password, email_valid, showLoading, } = this.state;
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <ImageBackground source={BG_IMAGE} style={styles.bgImage}>
            {this.state.fontLoaded ? 
            (
              <LoginForm
                loginButton={this.loginButton}
                setEmail={email}
                setPassword={password}
                password={password}
                email_valid={email_valid}
                showLoading={showLoading}
                navigation={this.props.navigation}
                changeStateValue={this.changeStateValue}
              />

            )
```

Child Component

```
export default function LoginForm (props)  {
    const { email, password, email_valid, showLoading } = props;

    return(
        <View style={styles.loginView}>
            <View style={styles.loginTitle}>
                <Image 
                    style={styles.imageCard} 
                    source={RAPIO_LOGO}
                />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.loginInput}>
            <FormInput
                icon="user"
                containerStyle={{ marginVertical: 10 }}
                onChangeText={setEmail => {
                    props.changeStateValue(setEmail)
                    // this.passwordInput.focus();
                    }}
                value={email}
                inputStyle={{ marginLeft: 10, color: 'white' }}
                keyboardAppearance="light"
                placeholder="Email"
                autoFocus={false}
                autoCapitalize="none"
                autoCorrect={false}
                keyboardType="email-address"
                returnKeyType="next"
                onSubmitEditing={() => {
                props.changeStateValue(e)
                this.passwordInput.focus();
                }}
                blurOnSubmit={false}
                placeholderTextColor="white"
                errorStyle={{ textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 12 }}
                errorMessage={
                email_valid ? null : 'Please enter a valid email address'
                }
            />
            <FormInput
                icon="lock"
                containerStyle={{ marginVertical: 10 }}
                onChangeText={setPassword => {
                    props.changeStateValue(setPassword)
                    // this.passwordInput.focus();
                    }}
                value={password}
                inputStyle={{ marginLeft: 10, color: 'white' }}
                secureTextEntry={true}
                keyboardAppearance="light"
                placeholder="Password"
                autoCapitalize="none"
                autoCorrect={false}
                keyboardType="default"
                returnKeyType="done"
                blurOnSubmit={true}
                placeholderTextColor="white"
                onSubmitEditing={props.loginButton}
            />
            </View>
            <Button
            title="LOG IN"
            containerStyle={{ flex: -1 }}
            buttonStyle={styles.signUpButton}
            titleStyle={styles.signUpButtonText}
            onPress={props.loginButton}
            loading={showLoading}
            loadingProps={{ size: 'small', color: 'white' }}
            disabled={!email_valid && password.length < 8}
            />
            <View style={styles.footerView}>
            <Text style={{ color: 'white', marginBottom: 15, }}>New here?</Text>
            <Button
                title="Create an Account"
                clear
                activeOpacity={0.5}
                titleStyle={styles.loginHereText}
                titleStyle={{ color: '#dd016b', fontSize: 15 }}
                buttonStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}
                containerStyle={{ marginTop: -10 }}
                onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SignupView')}
            />
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. Sorry for the confusing title. It wasn't using a event listener, but a regular event.

What I needed to do was create a normal function where I pass on two parameters, and when I pass on the parameters in my child I needed to identify both parameters

Function in the parent

```
changeStateValue =(setEmail, setPassword)=> {
      this.setState({
        email:setEmail,
        password: setPassword,
        email_valid: this.validateEmail(setEmail),
      })
    }
```

Passing on parameters in child

```
//For email input
onChangeText={setEmail => {
  props.changeStateValue(setEmail, props.setPassword)
}}
//For password input
onChangeText={setPassword => {
  props.changeStateValue(setPassword, props.setEmail)
}}
```